# Stripe API in python gives incorrect number of transactions

Tags: python, api, transactions, payment

This is my code for retrieving the number of transactions in Stripe API

```
import stripe
customers = stripe.Customer.list()
print(len(customers))
```

The above code always prints `10` in the output. I am using the test public and private keys that Stripe website has given me. What part of my code is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Stripe API docs, the default limit for requesting a list of customers is 10. That is likely why you are only ending up with 10 customers instead of your entire list.

As is the case with many such APIs, the documentation includes a parameter to enable pagination, `starting_after` or `ending_before`. You can read more about to Stripe's API [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list) - I would recommend building up your API doc reading muscles since I've personally found them to be incredibly helpful when working with a project like this.

Comment: adding this line fixed the problem  'customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100000)'